# Querying HTML document using XPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I have an HTML document that I would like to query using C# and XPath. What I am searching for is an XPath expression - not XSLT, C#, PHP or any other language-specific code samples. Any help will be highly appreciated but the XPath expression is all I need :).

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <p>
      <span>text</span>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <span>text</span>
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p>
      <span>This text is static and will never change</span>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <span>Bla bla bla .... more bla bla bla</span>
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p>
      <span>text</span>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <span>text</span>
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The XPath expression that I am looking for will extract the text that is currently represented by the string instance "Bla bla bla .... more bla bla bla". This text will vary from HTML document to HTML document but one string is ALWAYS the same. In this case that string is represented as "This text is static and will never change".

"This text is static and will never change" and "Bla bla bla .... more bla bla bla" are of course not the true strings - i replaced them because they are domain specific, not relevant to the problem and they reveal sensitive data that must not be shown!

Again, any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Using what language - PHP? JavaScript? HTML alone cannot do this. Please edit the question to tag a language.

Comment: @Utkanos: XPath expressions are language-independent.

Comment: I am aware of that, but he/she's going to be implementing it in some language. He/she's re-tagged it as C#.

Comment: Not necessarily. Tools such as `xmlstarlet` take a raw XPath expression.

Comment: I tried something like "//span[preceding-sibling/text() = 'some text']/text()" but that didn't do the trick

Comment: If you know that text you are looking for, why then would you need to extract it from the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/tr[2]/td[2]/p/span/text()
```

When this XPath expression is evaluated against the following XML document (obtained by turning the provided malformed HTML into a wellformed XML document):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <span>text</span>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                <span>text</span>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <span>Some text</span>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                <span>text to extract</span>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <span>text</span>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                <span>text</span>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**the text node with value `"text to extract"` is selected, as required**.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     "<xsl:copy-of select="/*/tr[2]/td[2]/p/span/text()"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
"text to extract"
```

**Alternatively, if you know the text but want to select an element containing it (say `td`), then use**:

```
//text()[. = 'text to extract']/ancestor::td[1]
```

Again with XSLT-based verification:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "//text()[. = 'text to extract']/ancestor::td[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The result now is**:

```
<td>
   <p>
      <span>text to extract</span>
   </p>
</td>
```

**Still another guess**:

If you want to find the closest *preceding* text node, then use:

```
//text()[. = 'text to extract']/preceding::text()[1]
```

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     "<xsl:copy-of select=
      "//text()[. = 'text to extract']/preceding::text()[1]"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
"Some text"
```

**Update**:

After the latest update by the OP, and his new explanation, the XPath expression he is looking for is:

```
//text()[. = 'This text is static and will never change']/following::text()[1]
```

This selects the text node with string value:

```
"Bla bla bla .... more bla bla bla"
```

Comment: Unfortunately `[2]` is too specific here; it needs to anchor on "Some text", not the absolute position.

Comment: As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrahams said ...this is just a sample piece of HTML to show the structure. There could be a thousand rows preceding or following the 2 interesting ones. The structure is of course that same though.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Seems you and I have different understanding of the question. I will edit the answer and provide a second expression, based on your understanding.

Comment: @KevinJohnson, If you know that text you are looking for, why then would you need to extract it from the document?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I only know what precedes the text I am searching for. In this case it is ALWAYS "Some text". But the string "Text to extract" will be different from document to document.

Comment: @KevinJohnson, I have updated my answer (at the end) with an alternative solution that seems to match more closely your understanding of the question.

Comment: @KevinJohnson, Please, edit the question and explicitly specify what node(s) you want to be selected. This is now missing and is cause for confusion.

Comment: @KevinJohnson, See my second update -- this is an XPath expression that selects the closest preceding text node of the one, whose identifying string value is known.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I edited my question. Please have a look at it again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I put all of your answers together to derive the correct expression. Thanks for all of your help!